# Apple Music: How to view the list of all loved items?

Tags: apple-music

I'm kind of OCD and like to know what data is behind every recommendation system.

Is there a way to view all the loved (hearted) items (songs, playlists, etc.) in Apple Music?

I believe at worst case scenario one could [just reset them](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204842).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I’m guessing these answers didn’t solve your problem. They didn’t solve mine. Insead I went and got my data from Apple:

1. Head to Apple’s [Data and Privacy](https://privacy.apple.com) portal.
2. Log in with the `Apple ID` for which you’d like to download data.
3. Under `Get a copy of your data`, click `Request a copy of your data`.
4. Select `Apple media services information`, then press `Continue`.
5. Now click `Complete the request`.
6. Wait a frickin’ week!
7. Download the file they email you a link to.
8. Inside the zip you will find another zip called `apple_media_services.zip`.
9. Inside *that* zip you will find `Apple Music Likes and Dislikes.csv`.

Super irritating that you have to go through such process to find this.

Comment: This should be the answer. The others only show a subset.

Comment: Whoa! Yes, this is a very open-minded and clever way to do it. 
Feels like cheating, though. :)
Agree that it is irritating and hope that there would be an UI for this one time.

Answer (score 2):

If you are listening in iTunes you can make a smart playlist which automatically adds all loved songs to it.

[image]

Note that this playlist will only contain songs that you "loved" on each respective device. I.e. if you love a song on your iPhone it will not appear in your "loved songs" smart playlist on your mac, or vice versa. This appears to be a syncing bug which may or may not be fixed one day.

Comment: Thanks, but it displays only songs and only those were added to My Music. That playlist does not display any song that was loved from Radio or New section for example.

Answer (score -1):

Just figured this out myself today, so here's how to do it:

1. Click the heart button (♥) to Love the song
2. Click the 3-dot button (...) and then click **Add to My Music**
3. Create a Smart Playlist where "Loved" = "is true"

Enjoy!

Comment: This is a ridicules solution by Apple. It only shows stuff that you liked and that is inside your library, not what you liked on Apple music